# error hanlders not working properly in express together with nuxtjs

Tags: express, nuxt.js

I am using `Nuxtjs` as a middleware in `expressjs`, and I have problems with handling errors in express server part.

When browser goes to 'localhost:3000', it will throw `res.status is not a function` error. when I comment that code block, everything is good expect that I cannot handle with uncaught server errors...

Any ideas?

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', path: 'server/.env' })

import express from 'express'
import { ready } from 'consola'
import { Nuxt, Builder } from 'nuxt'
import cors from 'cors'
import { json, urlencoded } from 'body-parser'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import passport from 'passport'
import './utils/auth'
import router from './routes'

const app = express()

app.use(json({ limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors())
app.use(passport.initialize())

app.use('/api', router)
app.use('/api/*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).end()
})

// error handlers
// it is problematic
// app.use((err, req, res) => {
//     res.status(err.status || 500).end()
// })

let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

async function start() {
    const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

    if (config.dev) {
        const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
        await builder.build()
    }

    app.use(nuxt.render)

    const host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1'
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

    app.set('port', port)
    app.listen(port, host)
    ready({
        message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
        badge: true,
    })
}
start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Without testing this code myself, I had a similar issue with my custom error handler and realized at one point I removed the `next` argument and it was failing. Can't say it will fix the issue because you are getting an error about `res`. I read through this page a few times and noticed a few mistakes I was making because I was using `async` functions.

[Error Handling Guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) may provide some help if you look over it carefully, but more specifically my comment about `next` is found under the title **Writing error handlers**

I wanted to say it might be arrow functions, but I don't see why that would break the logic here.